# L-stages in ill-founded countable model of ZFC

Tags: set-theory

I apologize that I need a preamble in which I digress into philosophy, but here it goes:

One of the perceived goals of set-theory is to provide a foundation for mathematics.  Natural, rational, real numbers and other structures can be defined inside set-theory.  However, students reason about these numbers and structures independently of set-theory. Numbers for example are not naturally perceived as sets, they are atomic, and sets are only needed to collect things.
Even in the context of model theory, I feel that I am allowed to work with a model of set-theory, put it aside for a moment, and think about non-set-theoretic objects. They all may coexist independently. I may believe that our "real" sets are sufficiently correctly described by ZFC, so that I believe in the existence of ordinals up to and beyond say $\omega_1$, again
alongside other non-set-theoretic atomic objects and structures. I may also have a notion of countable and uncountable collections independent of a concrete set-theoretical framework. Countable collections are enumerable, uncountable are not. This is the key idea of Cantors' diagonalization - there is no exhaustive enumeration of the reals.

End of preamble.

Assume a model of ZFC which is presented as a directed graph: The model universe is the collection of vertices, the element relation is the collection of edges. Vertices are atomic, they are not sets, they represent sets.  I choose this representation to avoid distracting concepts around real set membership.

Given such presentation of a model, one can identify some exemplary model-sets. The empty set of the model is represented by the vertex with no inbound edges. The set $\{\emptyset\}$ is represented by the vertex with not inbound edges except the one originating from the empty-set-vertex. And so on.

Define an external mapping $\operatorname{Vert}(s)$ which maps a model-set $s$ to the collection of vertices that represent $s$'s model-elements. Whatever $s$ is, $\operatorname{Vert}(s)$ is a countable collection of vertices, if the model is countable.

Assume we have an ill-founded countable model and want to identify various stages of the constructible universe of that model.

Wikipedia defines: $L_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \operatorname{Def} (L_\beta)$

It is not clear to me which ordinals I need to use to construct stages. Is it the "real" ones or the ones the model sees? However, I have an issue with both choices.

Choice 1: Use real (i.e. external) ordinals. I assume that the stages $L_\circ$ satisfy $L_\alpha \subsetneq L_\beta$ for $\alpha < \beta$. If this is so, this should translate to $\operatorname{Vert}(L_\alpha) \subsetneq \operatorname{Vert}(L_\beta)$ for $\alpha < \beta$. Then according to [1], with $\omega_1$ begin externally uncountable, $\operatorname{Vert}(L_{\omega_1})$ should be an uncountable collection of vertices, which is impossible.

Choice 2: Use in-model ordinals. According to [2] there is an infinite reverse path of ordinal-vertices: $\alpha_0 \leftarrow \alpha_1 \leftarrow \alpha_2 \cdots$

How is $L_{\alpha_0}$ even well-defined, when there is no base-case for the recursive definition?

[1] [limit of uncountable strictly increasing sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114953/)

[2] [Infinite decreasing ordinal chain in ill-founded countable model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114574/)

Comment: I think this question would benefit from trimming - I really don't see what the preamble has to do with the question proper. To be honest, I don't see the point of any of the question before the paragraph beginning "Assume we have" - that's where the actual mathematical question starts, and the philosophical aside doesn't seem to relate to it.

Answer (score 7):

Every model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, ill-founded or not, has its own version $L^M$ of the $L$-hierarchy constructed internally. The levels of $L^M$ are indexed by the $M$-ordinals.

While the $M$-ordinals may be ill-founded *externally*, they appear well-founded *internally*. This makes ordinal-indexed constructions work well from $M$'s perspective: $M$ doesn't "see" a descending sequence in its own ordinals, so *as far as $M$ is concerned* there is (for example) only one possible candidate for $L_{\alpha_0}$. Note that **we know this has to be the case ahead of time** since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that transfinite recursion works as desired and $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Note that countability concerns and the cardinality of $M$ don't enter into this. Moreover, nothing special about the $L$-hierarchy is being used here, simply its status as a definable transfinite recursion construction.

---

EDIT: Per the comments below, I think it's a good idea for me to give a toy example of an "internal construction."

Let $\Sigma$ be the language consisting of a single constant symbol $0$, a single binary relation symbol $<$, a single unary function symbol $s$, and a single unary relation symbol $U$. Consider the theory $T$ whose axioms say the following:

- $<$ is a linear order with least element $0$, where each element has an immediate successor given by $s$ and each element other than $0$ has an immediate predecessor.
- $U(0)\wedge\neg U(s(0))\wedge \neg U(s(s(0))\wedge\neg U(s(s(s(0))))$, and $\forall x(U(x)\leftrightarrow U(s(s(s(s(x))))))$. (Intuitively, this says that $U$ names the elements divisible by $4$.)
- Finally, the full first-order induction scheme for all $\Sigma$-formulas.

There is an obvious "standard" model of $T$, but - per compactness - $T$ also has lots of "nonstandard" models (= models where $<$ is ill-founded). Let $M$ be a nonstandard model of $T$, and consider the following imagined dialogue between Alice and Bob:

Alice makes a particular claim about the definable ("internal") structure of $M$:

> There is **exactly one** $M$-definable unary relation $E$ such that $E(0^M)$ and for all $x\in M$ we have $E(x)\leftrightarrow \neg E(s^M(x))$.

Bob takes issue with this.

- "Wait a second!" Bob reasonably objects. "Clearly $E$ is meant to denote the set of even numbers. But (in the absence of addition or multiplication) we define evenness *recursively*, using the ordering alone, and this doesn't work in $M$ since $<^M$ is ill-founded!"
- "Yes," Alice responds, "that's true - **the most natural approach** to producing such an $E$ doesn't work. However, consider the formula $\eta(x)\equiv U(x)\vee U(s(s(x))).$ Then we have $$M\models \eta(0)\wedge\forall x(\eta(x)\leftrightarrow\neg \eta(s(x)))$$ as desired."
- "Well, that's not really fair," Bob says, "that was sort of a loophole: you've just reconstructed a desired relation from other built-in structure. Isn't that cheating?"
- "It would be cheating **if** that additional structure weren't part of $M$ itself," Alice answers. "I'm not claiming that we don't need $U$, but it would be silly not to use it if we're given it."
- "... OK, I think I see why I'm dissatisfied," Bob says. "You've used some of the 'extra structure' of $M$ to produce a definable function with the desired properties. But why should it be *unique*? By making things depend on structure other than $<$ alone, you've raised the possibility of having multiple such definable relations which disagree - which would clearly ruin your day."
- "True," admits Alice. "But I haven't used all the axioms of $T$ yet! Keep in mind I also have the **induction scheme** (which is first-order, so permits nonstandard models). Suppose $\psi(x)$ were some other formula such that $M\models\psi(0)\wedge\forall x(\psi(x)\leftrightarrow\psi(s(s(x)))$. Consider the *new* formula $\theta(x)\equiv \eta(x)\leftrightarrow\psi(x)$. We have $\theta(0)$ (trivially) and $\forall x(\theta(x)\rightarrow\theta(s(x)))$ (go by cases). So by our induction scheme we get $\forall x\theta(x)$, or to put it another way $\forall x(\eta(x)\leftrightarrow\psi(x))$. So $\psi$ defines **the same relation on $M$ as $\theta$**."

**The same thing is going on with the $L$-hierarchy internal to a nonstandard model $M$.** While ill-foundedness implies that the $M$-ordinals *alone* are insufficient for such a construction *even if we went beyond first-order logic*, the $M$-ordinals *together with the rest of $M$* give $M$ the power to produce a definable relation with the desired properties, and additional properties of $M$ (e.g. Foundation) ensure that exactly one definable relation with the desired properties exists. Moreover, there is a single formula which defines the desired definable relation within $M$ for *every* model $M$ (we don't have to use different formulas in different models).

Comment: What makes ZFC special that we care what it internally perceives as well-founded? What is an internal sequence anyway in the context of directed graphs? I assume one could translate Wikipedia's definition into a native graph construction. Begin with zero vertices, add the correct vertices and edges in each step. The external well-foundedness of the index set would be one ingredient to the construction's well-definedness. At which point would a graph theorist care about internal sequences?

Comment: @Damian "What makes ZFC special that we care what it internally perceives as well-founded?" As model theorists, we always care about the definable sets in a structure and the "internal second-order" behavior of those definable sets, and well-foundedness is important to $\mathsf{ZFC}$. "What is an internal sequence anyway in the context of directed graphs?" Just write down the definition of "sequence" in the language of set theory and replace each "$\in$" with the edge relation. "At which point would a graph theorist care about internal sequences?" I don't know, I'm not a graph theorist.

Comment: My point is that a graph theorist should be able to produce the same results as a set theorist as long as he knows how to apply the definition of the construction. It is the choice of the set theorist to interpret some vertex as a sequence, it is not a necessity of model theory.

The graph theorist is given a graph without context and a recipe to recursively construct subgraphs. He cannot construct the subgraph of $L_{\alpha_0}$ because it is ill-defined. $L_\circ$ is not a construction, it is a description at best. I wouldn't be surprised if $L_\circ$ is ambiguous even in a fixed model.

Comment: @Damian "My point is that a graph theorist should be able to produce the same results as a set theorist as long as he knows how to apply the definition of the construction" They can. "It is the choice of the set theorist to interpret some vertex as a sequence, it is not a necessity of model theory." ??? "He cannot construct the subgraph of $L_{\alpha_0}$ because it is ill-defined" That's **wrong**. "$L_\circ$ is not a construction, it is a description at best." That's also **wrong**.  "I wouldn't be surprised if $L_\circ$ is ambiguous even in a fixed model." Well, math is surprising sometimes.

Comment: @Damian It may help to think of it this way. There is a particular **extremely complicated** formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in the language of graph theory such that, when $M$ is a "ZFC-graph,"$\varphi(x,y)$ defines in $M$ a relation between "$M$-ordinals" and certain other vertices of $M$ and this relation satisfies certain graph-theoretic properties - for example, the set of vertices in $M$ which appear as right coordinates of pairs satisfying $\varphi$ constitutes the smallest definable subset of $M$ which is itself a "ZFC-graph" (think about the classical "minimality" of $L$). (con'td)

Comment: Intuitively, $\varphi(x,y)$ means "$y\in L_x$." All of this can be parsed by a graph theorist, the only point of difference between the graph theorist and the set theorist being that the graph theorist **might not care** about this particular extremely complicated formula. The "internal transfinite recursion" nature of $\varphi$ is a precise property, having to do with the graph-theoretic rephrasing of the set-theoretic recursion theorem, and understanding such internal constructions is crucial to studying ill-founded models of set theory.

Comment: Maybe stepping back from ZFC will help me. Let us have a definition in the context of PA: $K(0) := 1$, $K(s(n)) := -K(n)$.
Consider a nonstandard countable model. Presumably there is a chain $\cdots, n_{-2}, n_{-1}, n_0, n_1, n_2, \cdots$ with $n_{i+1} = s(n_i)$. Is $K(n_0)$ positive or negative?

Comment: I am sorry to have chosen numbers, I should have used true/false, black/white. My point is that the definition might work for the initial segment of the model, but is, I think, ill-defined for those on the $\mathbb{Z}$-like chain. This is how I see the definition of $L_\circ$ right now.

Comment: @Damian OK, do the following. Within the language of arithmetic there is a particular formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which we can prove in $\mathsf{PA}$ defines a function $K$ with the following properties: $K(n)=n$ mod $2$ for example: $K(0)=0$, $K(x)=0$ implies $K(s(x))=1$, and $K(x)=1$ implies $K(s(x))=0$. Now for each $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ (ill-founded or not) and each $n\in M$ (nonstandard or not) we can ask "What is $K(n)$ (in the sense of $M$)?" **And $M$ will have an answer to that**. To us in the "standard" universe this may look silly if $n$ is nonstandard. (cont'd)

Comment: But there's nothing problematic about this at all. Things only look weird if we expect $M$ to hew too closely to "standard reality." Instead, we need to think in the following way: the theorems we prove about our various recursive constructions are $\mathsf{PA}$-theorems, and so must hold in any model of $\mathsf{PA}$, standard or not. So **every model of $\mathsf{PA}$ has its "own version" of the usual arithmetical constructions**, no matter how weird that may look.

Comment: @Damian "My point is that the definition might work for the initial segment of the model, but is, I think, ill-defined for those on the $\mathbb{Z}$-like chain." That is, again, **incorrect**. (Also there is no "**the** $\mathbb{Z}$-chain" - there are many, many, many different $\mathbb{Z}$-chains. I think you instead mean "ill-founded part.") "This is how I see the definition of $L_\circ$ right now." That will change over time as you come to better understand illfounded models.

Comment: "And M will have an answer to that". Do you need to introduce $K$ as a new function symbol for that?

Comment: @Damian No. Really there's no need for the notation $K$ at all here, that's just convenient notation given how we write arguments in natural language. Forget $K$; the point is that we have some formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in the language of $\mathsf{PA}$ such that $\mathsf{PA}$ proves: for each $x$ there is exactly one $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$, and that $y$ is either $0$ or $1$; $\varphi(0,0)$; $\forall x(\varphi(x,0)\leftrightarrow\neg \varphi(s(x),0))$. In any model $M\models \mathsf{PA}$ we get a function $K_M:M\rightarrow M$ given by $K_M(x)$ = the unique $y$ so that $M\models\varphi(x,y)$.

Comment: (E.g. $\varphi(x,y)\equiv (y=0\vee y=s(0))\wedge\exists z(z+z+y=x)$.) One special case of this is the standard model's version, $K_\mathbb{N}$. We may think of $K_\mathbb{N}$ as being **built from only the ordering**, and certainly this breaks down for nonstandard models: we can have $M_1,M_2\models\mathsf{PA}$ with  isomorphic underlying orders (that is, $M_1\upharpoonright \{<\}\cong M_2\upharpoonright \{<\}$) which nonetheless have $K_{M_1}\not=K_{M_2}$. But so what? A model $M$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ is **more than just an ordering**, and the construction of $K_M$ uses that additional structure.

Comment: @Damian I've added a toy example of an "internal construction" (+ subsequent analysis) which may help clarify things.

Comment: @Damian: You can argue that any programmer in C should be able to produce the same results as someone who is writing a software in Python or Common Lisp. And yet, you find different software is written in different languages, usually to highlight strengths of the chosen language over another. Saying that a graph theorist could derive all of set theory since a model of ZFC can be seen as a graph is too reductionist and it misses the big picture of where the strength of the structure and theory lie in.

Comment: @Noah, given a model of PA, $\varphi$ and some $x$, one would need to search the whole model for a fitting $z$ to figure out $y$. One needs the whole model in advance. This is ok, as $\varphi$'s task is not to construct its ambient universe.
For the $L$ construction, Wikipedia states "... quantifiers interpreted to range over the previous stage". My definition of $K$ also used previously known things to define a new thing. This property got lost when translated into $\varphi$. So I don't know if we have different opinions what should count as a construction, or if the example is unsuitable.